# Parameterized Query in VB.net with Null Date in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have the following VB.Net Code to insert a row in an Oracle Table

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO Roles_ (ACTIVE,ACTIVATIONDATE,DEACTIVATIONDATE,CANBEDELETED,FRIENDLYNAME) VALUES  (:ACTIVE, :ACTIVATIONDATE, :DEACTIVATIONDATE, :CANBEDELETED, :FRIENDLYNAME)"

            Command.CommandText = SQL
            Command.Parameters.Add("ACTIVE", IIf(Active, "y", "n"))
            Command.Parameters.Add("CANBEDELETED", IIf(CanBeDeleted, "y", "n"))
            Command.Parameters.Add("FRIENDLYNAME", RoleFiendlyName)

            If IsNothing(ActivationDate) Then
                Using Param As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter()
                    Param.ParameterName = "ACTIVATIONDATE"
                    Param.DbType = DbType.DateTime
                    Param.Value = DBNull.Value
                    Command.Parameters.Add(Param)
                End Using                    
            Else
                Command.Parameters.Add("ACTIVATIONDATE", ActivationDate)
            End If

            If IsNothing(DeactivationDate) Then
                Using Param As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter()
                    Param.ParameterName = "DEACTIVATIONDATE"
                    Param.DbType = DbType.DateTime
                    Param.Value = DBNull.Value
                    Command.Parameters.Add(Param)
                End Using                    
            Else
                Command.Parameters.Add("DEACTIVATIONDATE", DeactivationDate)
            End If

            Try
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch Ex As OracleException
                msgbox(Ex.Message)
            Catch Ex As Exception
                msgbox(Ex.Message)
            End Try
```

The values of the parameters are :

```
Active = true                 'Boolean
CanBeDeleted = True           'Boolean 
FriendlyName = "Test"         'String
ActivationDate = nothing      'Date
DeactivationDate = nothing    'Date
```

but when I run the code I receive the error : "ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"

Does anyone know what is wrong with this code please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the parameters are not added in the same order as in the SQL query, the command should requires binding by name.

```
Command.Bindbyname = true
```